# Cannot copy multiple excel columns at once with pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to copy multiple columns from one xlsx file to another, my code only works for copying only one column, how can I copy more than one?

```
column = data_Sheet['NDB_No']

with pd.ExcelWriter('parsedData.xlsx', mode='w') as writer:
    column.to_excel(writer, sheet_name= "new sheet name", index = False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose multiple columns from one dataframe like this:

```
list_of_columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3',...] ## Put your actual columns here
columns = data_Sheet[list_of_columns]
```

Now write this into another excel:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('parsedData.xlsx', mode='w') as writer:
    columns.to_excel(writer, sheet_name= "new sheet name", index = False)
```